# How do I export the groupwise database into .pst or .csv format?

Tags: exchange, opensuse, novell, outlook, groupwise

I have only an ssh connection to the server and I need to extract the groupwise database and import all the users and hopefully emails too into MS Exchange.
When you google for tools, the only thing that pops up are .exe files (What part of SUSE uses .exe files I wonder) which make no sense.

How do I dump the groupwise database into a flat single file that is MS friendly?

```
gw1:/media/nss/GRPWISE/mainpo # rpm -qa | grep groupwise
novell-groupwise-agents-12.0.2-108211
novell-groupwise-admin-12.0.2-108211
novell-groupwise-gwha-12.0.2-108211
novell-groupwise-gwcheck-12.0.2-108211
novell-groupwise-gwdva-12.0.2-108211
```

Answer (score 2):

You use ldapsearch and don't forget -ZZ for proper authentication